# SQL where in clause with array of array

Tags: sql-server

I know that the `WHERE ... IN ...` clause allows to select all values of a field that exists in a given array. How do I expand this idea to a group of fields? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE (First, Last) IN ((Adam, Scott), (Betty, Johnson), (Cathy, Wyatt))
```

Or any other method that allows the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax in the question is valid in some other RDBMSs but not SQL Server. If on 2008+ you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name t
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM   (VALUES ('Adam', 'Scott'),
                             ('Betty','Johnson'),
                             ('Cathy','Wyatt')
                              ) v(first, last)
              WHERE t.first = v.first AND t.last = f.last
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are after really. If you just want to combine 2 fields then you can use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE First+','+Last IN ('Adam, Scott', 'Betty, Johnson', 'Cathy, Wyatt')
```

Comment: @NickyThai it should do. Though relies on commas not being valid in the columns being concatenated.

Comment: What do you mean? If your `table_name` has string type columns named `First` and `Last` then it will work fine.

Comment: @MartinSmith, @Malk I got the error `Invalid column name ','` I tried both single quote and double quote.

Comment: Double quotes it will be treated as an object identifier under default settings and give you that error. Single quotes should work though...

Answer (score -3):

SELECT * FROM Table_name
WHERE First IN ('Adam', 'Betty', 'Cathy')
AND Last IN ('Scott', 'Johnson', 'Wyatt')

Comment: This will return rows with names matching any of the 9 permutations of those names. Not just the three desired.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's true, but I don't see where the question says that wasn't a desirable outcome. He or she could have been more specific that they want to return only rows where the first name and the last name were matched.